# Jsf form and <p: or <h: messages tag

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple jsf form. It's working there isn't any problem with this. 
It's look like this way:

```
                <h:form>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Something::" for="bo_close_select"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mainKallerBean.chosedBoCloseType}" styleClass="form-control">
                        <f:selectItems var="item" itemLabel="#{item.description}" itemValue="#{item.id}" value="#{mainKallerBean.showBoCloseTypes()}"></f:selectItems>

                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="comment:" for="bo_comment"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputTextarea value="#{mainKallerBean.boCommentText}" id="bo_comment" styleClass="comment_text_bo_class"  rows="5" cols="45">

                    </h:inputTextarea>
                    <h:outputLabel value="num:" for="bo_wf_num"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:inputText value="#{mainKallerBean.boSrNum}" styleClass="form-control" id="bo_wf_num"></h:inputText>

                    <p:separator></p:separator>

                    <h:commandButton action="#{mainKallerBean.saveKallerBoDone()}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Save"></h:commandButton>

                </h:form>
```

But, when I try to add `<p:messages closable="true" ></p:messages>`tag to it, in my browser i can see an error message:

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion:
>        enclose the necessary components within h:form

But the messages tag is inside the h:form tag.

I try to create an empty form for messages tag, but it throws the same error message too.

Could anybody please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Version info? Especially jsf implementation version?

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a warning, not an error.
And you only get to see warning messages if you are in development mode in your faces configuration.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the reason this warning appears in the first place is a bug so I suggest you don't overthink it

Comment: Bug where? Windows 10? Edge? ;-)

Comment: mojara < 2.1.1 https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1663

Comment: Thanks, so in that case it is a duplicate of one of the other stackoverflow posts?

Comment: most certainly, yes ;)

Comment: Please mark it as such then, thanks and cheers